# RuntimeException: Application "org.eclipse.ui.ide.workbench" could not be found in the registry

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, eclipse-plugin

I am using jdk 1.7 and ubuntu 16.04.
I am getting runtime exception in log file when I am going to start Eclipse

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Application "org.eclipse.ui.ide.workbench"
>   could not be found in the registry. The applications available are:
>   org.eclipse.ant.core.antRunner, org.eclipse.equinox.app.error,
>   org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director,
>   org.eclipse.equinox.p2.garbagecollector.application,
>   org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher.InstallPublisher,
>   org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher.EclipseGenerator,
>   org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher.ProductPublisher,
>   org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher.FeaturesAndBundlesPublisher,
>   org.eclipse.equinox.p2.reconciler.application,
>   org.eclipse.equinox.p2.repository.repo2runnable,
>   org.eclipse.equinox.p2.repository.metadataverifier,
>   org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository.mirrorApplication,
>   org.eclipse.equinox.p2.metadata.repository.mirrorApplication,
>   org.eclipse.equinox.p2.touchpoint.natives.nativePackageExtractor,
>   org.eclipse.equinox.p2.updatesite.UpdateSitePublisher,
>   org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher.UpdateSitePublisher,
>   org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher.CategoryPublisher,
>   org.eclipse.pde.build.Build.  at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppContainer.startDefaultApp(EclipseAppContainer.java:248)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.MainApplicationLauncher.run(MainApplicationLauncher.java:29)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:388)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:243)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:673)  at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:610)     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1519)     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1492)

Comment: Which version of Eclipse? Installed how?

Comment: using eclipse mars